# Crontab jobs schedule

Tags: python, cron

I am pretty new to Unix system. I am trying to schedule a python job in crontab as below;

```
42 15 18 4 *  absolute_path_where_python_is_install absolute_path_to_python_script > absolute_path_to_output_log_file
```

This does nothing: no error, no output
However, when I run the code below manually, it works as expected

```
absolute_path_where_python_is_install absolute_path_to_python_script > absolute_path_to_output_log_file
```

Can somebody please help me to identify what I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check you environment and see if anything is set there that you use. For instance if you are setting a PYTHONPATH in you env, then that will not be available at crontab runtime.

Comment: Also check you crontab. `* * * * * date >> /tmp/ping` is a good way to make sure crontab is running as expected.

Comment: See if your cron is running or not by `sudo service cron status` and `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` see the logs from syslog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things to check to debug:

1.) Make sure crontab is running. Add

```
* * * * * date >> /tmp/ping
```

and check that file to ensure you daemon is working as expected.

2.) Check the error from the script on run. Now you only capture stdout. Capture the stderr and see if you can catch an error message

```
* * * * * python script.py > script.log 2>&1
```

Adding `2>&1` is a redirect that redirects file descriptor 2 (stderr) into file descriptor 1 (stdout) which is being sent to the log file, meaning both stdout and stderr will end up in the log file.

3.) Validate that the env is as expected at runtime:

```
* * * * * env | sort > /tmp/env_in_cron
```

and then run

```
env | sort > /tmp/env_at_runtime

sdiff /tmp/env_at_runtme /tmp/env_in_cron
```

and see if anything you might need is not their (And notice how different the environments are). If you are missing something you can either

a.) Add the single parameter

```
* * * * * PYTHONPATH=/python/lib/path python python-script.py > python-script.log
```

b.) or just source the full env.

```
* * * * * . /home/user/.profile && python python-script.py > python-script.log
```

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/1158990/gbtimmonThanks a lot it works perfectly now with option b.

Comment: I created a .profile with PYTHONPATH and in the crontab i did something like;
* * * * * /path/to/.profile python-script.py >> python-script.log 2>&1